# $\ln\left(1+x\right)=x-\dfrac{x^2}{2}+\dfrac{x^3}{3}+\dots$ when $|x|<1$ or $x=1$.

Tags: taylor-expansion

$\ln\left(1+x\right)=x-\dfrac{x^2}{2}+\dfrac{x^3}{3}+\dots$ when $|x|<1$ or $x=1$. Why is the restriction $|x|<1$ or $x=1$? I know from Wikipedia that it is because out of this restriction, the function's "Taylor approximation" is not fair. But how did we derive this limit?

Comment: Can you evaluate the "radius of convergence" of a power series?

Comment: No, Sir, I have heard it first time.

Comment: If $|x|>1$ then the right hand side of the equation diverges. But the left hand side of the equation will evaluate to a definite value, so $|x|$ cannot be more than 1.

Comment: @LeeYiyuan, Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many good answers online about this. A brief description is that any series on the form:

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_n z^n$

for constants $c_n$ will converge at $|z|<r$, possible converge or diverge at $|z|=r$ (on a case-by-case basis), and diverge at $|z|>r$, for some $r$. This holds for complex numbers where $|z|$ is taken to be the norm of the complex number, or real numbers where $|z|$ is taken to be the absolute value.

In a series like $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!} x^{2n+1}$ we have $r=\infty$, and in a series like $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n^n x^n$ we have $r=0$. ($6!=6*5*4*3*2*1$ is the factorial symbol)

[Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RadiusofConvergence.html)

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence)

Comment: How did you derive $r$ for $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!} x^{2n+1}$ as well as $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n^n x^n$?

Comment: @Sush See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test#The_test and try plugging in the terms (that is, $a_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!} x^{2n+1}$) and necessitating that $L$ is less than 1. In the first one you should see that L is equal to zero regardless of $x$, and in the second case you should see that $L$ diverges to infinity regardless of $x$ (unless $x=0$).

Comment: I can't provide an intuitive proof of this, but it should make sense. For the sum of $a_n$ to converge, each term $a_n$ has to get smaller and smaller fast enough. If it goes to zero too slowly (like the harmonic series) it will diverge. $lim_{n\to \infty}|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|$ can be seen as a measure of how fast the sequence decreases, and so if it's fast enough, it converges. If you're familiar with the notation http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Ratio_Test may be of help.

Comment: Thank you so much , Sir, I will have to invest considerably long time to understand each answer fully.

Answer (score 2):

The written form above can be reduced to this one: $$f(x)=\ln |1+x|=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{x^n}{n}$$ When we read the chapter of infinite series in any advanced calculus book, we see a section called *The Power series*. In this section, we learn how to use these kind of series in Calculus. Meanwhile, we learn if a function $f(x)$ and its derivatives $f'(x),f''(x),\cdots,f^{(n)}(x)$ exist and are continuous in interval $I=[a,b]$ and also $f^{(n+1)}(x)$ exists in interval $(a,b)$; then the function can be written as follows: $$f(x)=f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)+\cdots+\frac{f^{(n)}(x)}{n!}(x-a)^n+R_n$$ in which $R_n$ is the reminder. For a suitable interval $I$ we can check that $R_n\to 0$. Note that in this case we choose $a=0$. Now, what is this proper interval? Indeed, the ratio test can be used here to give us that interval.

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks my dear friend. Xmas Amy. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The standard approach is to consider the derivatives of both functions. On the right you obtain $\sum(-x)^n$, which you may recognize as a [geometric series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula), with sum $\frac1{1+x}$, the formula being valid for $|x|<1$. But this is also the derivative of the function on the left. This means the two functions are equal, up to a constant. Evaluate both functions at $x=0$ to see that the constant is zero.

The above leaves a few blanks, of course. Notably, that the power series converges for $|x|<1$ and that we can differentiate it term by term in this interval. This follows from general [results](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence#Theoretical_radius) on the radius of convergence of power series, and on [uniformly convergent sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence#To_differentiability) of functions.

What the argument does *not* show is that the equality also holds at $x=1$. This needs a separate proof, and follows from a general [theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem) due to Abel. Since the series [diverges](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_%28mathematics%29#Divergence) when $x=-1$, the equality does not hold (for $x$ real) beyond the region $-1<x\le 1$.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is why $|x|<1$ and x=1. The reason is that the formula is not valid for $x=-1$. So we can't say $|x| \le 1$ as we want to exclude $x = -1$.

The limit has to be less than $1$ as $\log(1+x)$ blows up at $-1$. To show that we can get this close to $1$ requires more analysis.